# How to get the database update script from the last migration?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Today I'm using EF migrations in the following way: I use

```
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName
```

to create a new migration, and then

```
dotnet ef database update
```

to apply the last update to the database.

Now, if I *just want* the last migration database update script to be generated is there a way using dotnet ef?

I mean, obviously before applying, the toolchain has to generate the script, which is then submited to the database.

Is there a way to just output the script without applying to the database?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
  dotnet ef migrations script -from (MigrationYouWant-1) -to MigrationYouWant
```

to create the SQL script (so basically everything is scripted between "from" and "to", "from" excluded and "to" included).
You can find more info on the topic here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: This won't work in .net 7